# How to autotypecast the result of a function call?

Tags: c++

I want to avoid the cast in factory calls like this

```
MyObject* O = dynamic_cast<MyObject* >( Factory->Create("MyObject") );
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Can you include any more details on how your factory functions are implemented?

Comment: Can you switch to `Factory->Create<MyObject>()`?

Comment: I can use only string since the class names come from files.

Comment: Create returns void* now

Comment: If the class names come from files then you don't know them at compile time. And if so, you can't declare `O` as the correct type, but only as the base type returned by the factory.

Comment: If you know the exact type of the object at compile time, why use a factory at all? Just create the object.

Comment: If `"MyObject"` comes from a file, how do you know to cast it to `MyObject`?

Comment: @Smirno: Change your factory, returning `void*` is putting your foot right at the center of a bear trap => the slightest move and you lose your leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

```
struct sInstantiationProxy
{
private:
    void* Obj;
    sInstantiationProxy( void* O ): Obj( O ) {};
public:
    template<typename T> operator T()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T>( Obj );
    }
};
```

And later:

```
sInstantiationProxy Create( const std::string& ClassName ) const
{
    return sInstantiationProxy( Factory->Create( ClassName ) );
};
```

Now you can use global `Create()` function without `dynamic_cast`:

```
MyObject* O = Create( "MyObject" );
```

Comment: @Andrew: Changed ``dynamic_cast`` to ``reinterpret_cast``. My code where I use this snippet just does't use ``void*``. So, not it is fixed.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is always implementation-defined, which is a code smell. Although it does work in practice, I'd suggest static_cast instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No.  `reinterpret_cast` has very strict requirements in which it has a very standard-defined behavior.  You can take a `T*`, cast it to `void*`, then back to `T*` without invoking any implementation-defined behavior: do the same with a `Derived*` to `void*` to `Base*` and you are on thin ice.

Comment: Yes indeed, you can roundtrip A->B->A with reinterpret_cast, but you can do the same with static_cast provided that B is either a pointer to baseclass or a void pointer, so you're comparing apples to oranges here. Further, there are cases where a reinterpret_cast compiles (but bombs at runtime) while a static_cast doesn't compile. Call me paranoid, but I prefer compiler errors over runtime errors. Also, with C++98, the inverse of the implicit conversion to void* was a static_cast, while it wasn't guaranteed to work with a reinterpret_cast, which was the "implementation defined" part of it.

Answer (score 9):

Make the `Create` method a template?

```
template<typename T>
T* Create(const std::string& name) const
{
    return new T;  // Or what you want to do
}
```

Then you can do e.g

```
auto o = Factory->Create<MyObject>("MyObject");
```

Comment: Can you do it without template <MyObject>?

Comment: I don't want auto type here.

Comment: `auto` is not a type, it just tells the compiler to determine the type of the declaration from the type of what is used to initialize it. The meaning of this keyword was changed between C++98 and C++11, in the former it just explicitly gave an object automatic duration. Automatic duration is actually the default, which is why nobody used it in C++98.

Answer (score 2):

Make it return a helper object with a templatized type conversion operator.

```
class Helper
{
  void* obj;
public:
  template <class T> operator T()
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(obj);
  }
  .... Constructors etc
};
```

For added bonus, make it contain the typeid of the object, and check that it matches that of T.